# Найти элементы DOM по тексту и применить к элементам стиль

Tags: jquery, dom, css-selectors

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на *SPAN* применялся стиль ко всем *SPAN*, содержащим такое же слово, что и нажимаемый.

Есть вот такой код *HTML*:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span class="tag_w">распашные</span>
    <span class="tag_w">ворота</span>
    <span class="tag_w">came</span>
    <span class="tag_w">ati</span>
    <span class="tag_w">3000</span>
  </td>
  <td>91</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <span class="tag_w">привод</span>
    <span class="tag_w">+для</span>
    <span class="tag_w">распашных</span>
    <span class="tag_w">ворот</span>
    <span class="tag_w">came</span>
    <span class="tag_w">ati</span>
    <span class="tag_w">3000</span>
  </td>
  <td>68</td>
</tr>
```

и

```
$('span.tag_w').click(function () {
                var _spanText = $(this).text();
                $('span.tag_w:contains(_spanText)').css('color','green');
            });
```

Почему не получается через `contains()` и как тогда вообще решить эту задачу?

Comment: может следует _spanText вынести за кавычки здесь: $('span.tag_w:contains(_spanText)')? это переменная, а не часть строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы просто не сделали конкатенацию строк в селекторе. Вот рабочий вариант:

```js
$('span.tag_w').click(function () {
    var _spanText = $(this).text();
    $('span.tag_w:contains('+_spanText+')').css('color','green');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr><td>
  <span class="tag_w">распашные</span>
  <span class="tag_w">ворота</span>
  <span class="tag_w">came</span>
  <span class="tag_w">ati</span>
  <span class="tag_w">3000</span>
</td></tr>
```